# Sitecore Content Editor Ribbon Click Limit

Tags: menu, sitecore, ribbon, sitecore6, content-editor

Using the Sitecore content Editor, we have an issue after about 5 - 10 mouse clicks to the menu ribbon.  It becomes unresponsive...

[image: Sitecore content editor menu ribbon]

We have a number of users each with their own logins and the issue affects all of them on different computers and browsers.  Irrespective of what they click or do (it seems), but after a few clicks menu popup events do not fire, for example:

**Example:**
User logs in, clicks some options from the menu ribbon for a site, for example 'publish' or 'presentation - details'.  After about 5-10 clicks the user can still click the menu ribbon options, but nothing happens.  The sub-window popups do not popup.

The only solution we have found so far is to reload the entire page, which is not great because you have to find your place in the tree structure again etc.

We are using version:  Sitecore.NET 6.2.0 (rev. 091012)

Any ideas ?

Comment: Any JavaScript errors in the console?

Comment: Which browser are you using (although I realise SC6.2 is very limited in it's browser support...)

Comment: I do not notice any JavaScript errors in the console.

Comment: I think it might be a popup blocking mechanism of your browser. Can you check if you can add exception for your domain, e.g. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/pop-blocker-settings-exceptions-troubleshooting

Comment: This happens across any browser (Chrome, Firefox, IE) for all users (we have about 15 users)

Comment: Popups are not being blocked, the first 5-10 clicks are ok.

Comment: Sitecore 6.2 is not support on Chrome and Firefox has limited functionality. Even IE is supported up to version 8 only. https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164